# How to aggregate on nested objects in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

I have the following mapping in ES:

```
"mappings": {
    "products": {
        "properties": {
            "product": {
                "type" : "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "features": {
                        "type": "nested"
                    },
                    "sitedetails": {
                        "type": "nested"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then 3 products like this:

```
 "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "catalog",
        "_type": "products",
        "_id": "AVNE8F4mFYOWvB4rMqdO",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "product": {
              "ean": "abc",
              "features": {
                 "productType": "DVD player"
              },
              "color": "Black",
              "manufacturer": "Sony",
              "sitedetails": [
                 {
                    "name": "amazon.com",
                    "sku": "zzz",
                    "url": "http://www.amazon.com/dp/zzz"
                 }
              ],
              "category": "Portable DVD Players"
           }
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "catalog",
        "_type": "products",
        "_id": "AVNE8XkXFYOWvB4rMqdQ",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "product": {
              "ean": "def",
              "features": {
                 "ProductType": "MP3 player"
              },
              "color": "Black",
              "manufacturer": "LG",
              "sitedetails": [
                 {
                    "name": "amazon.com",
                    "sku": "aaa",
                    "url": "http://www.amazon.com/dp/aaa"
                 }
              ],
              "category": "MP3 Players"
           }
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "catalog",
        "_type": "products",
        "_id": "AVNIh-xVWwxj6Cz_r8AT",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "product": {
              "ean": "abc",
              "features": {
                 "productType": "DVD player"
              },
              "color": "White",
              "manufacturer": "Sony",
              "sitedetails": [
                 {
                    "name": "amazon.com",
                    "sku": "ggg",
                    "url": "http://www.amazon.com/dp/ggg"
                 }
              ],
              "category": "Portable DVD Players"
           }
        }
     }
  ]
```

I need to display on the UI side 2 filters, one for Manufacturer and one for website.
How can I aggregate on product.manufacturer and product.sitedetails.name?

tnx!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
GET /catalog/products/_search
{
"aggs": {
    "byManufacturer": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "product"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "byManufacturer": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "product.manufacturer"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    "bySeller": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "product.sitedetails"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "bySeller": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "product.sitedetails.name"
                    }
                }
            }
        }    
    }
}
```